# Longtable Duplicate Separator at Page Break

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, booktabs

I have a longtable spreading over 2 pages. Unfortunately, since I decided to use the booktabs package, I get a duplicate line separator between the table header of the second page and the next table entry. I found solutions like adding a `*` behind the `\\` but they didn't work.

I want to remove the annoying dashed line on the second page:

[image: visualization of example]

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{17cm}

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}llll@{}}\toprule
\# & A & B & C\\
\midrule
\endhead
1 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
2 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
A & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
3 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
4 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
5 & A & B & C\\
\hdashline
6 & A & B & C\\
\hdashline
7 & A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know `\endfirsthead` etc. commands? But in this case, it's sufficient to interchange `\midrule` and `\endhead`, in my point of view

Comment: I believe that `arydshline` breaks a little bit the advantages of `booktabs`, reducing the space, perhaps this only my impression

Comment: I've tracked the 'error' back that the page break occurs right before a `\hdashline`, such that this is shifted to the next page, making a double line with the `midrule` from `\endhead`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: no, then I have a dashed line as separator and not the midrule I want to have. Which other package do you suggest for dashed lines?

Comment: For dashed lines I have no other suggestion, it can be cured of course. I've some idea in mind ;-)

Comment: rather hard to fix that automatically I'd just not use the dashed lines, or remove the offending one by hand when the document is nearly done.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's what I had in mind when I was asking you about the `\ifsomething` stuff concerning a page break induced by `longtable`. Would this be really easying `supertab`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer so I guessed once I saw this q:-)

Answer (score 3):

Now you can try the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). It always uses `\toprule`, and `\bottomrule` in any table pages, and doesn't make duplicate line separators.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=5cm,width=7cm,height=4.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand{\hdashline}{\hline[dashed]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  halign = c,
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {@{}XXXX@{}}, rowhead = 1,
}
\toprule
  \# & A & B & C\\
\midrule
  1 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
  2 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
  3 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
  4 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
  5 & A & B & C\\
\hdashline
  6 & A & B & C\\
\hdashline
  7 & A & B & C \\
\hdashline
  8 & A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]